# Using Harmony-proxy on Webserver node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, es6-proxy

I have a node.js code that runs a webserver and in this I'll like to use proxy
Proxy link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy
I'm using this shim: https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect to load the proxy but it may require me to load the proxy in the cli rather than in node.js itself. Is there a way to load it in Node.js or is there another proxy that can be used to monitor changes in array for server-side code that will work far greater than client-side code as it will be receiving YUGE requests.

Comment: As for YUGE requests, it should be noticed that proxies are SLOW.

Comment: You don't think I can run thousands of requests per second, can you reference a graph or something I can use for comparison?

Comment: This will create additional load on the server, I don't know how exactly this will affect requests. Since Jsperf is down, you can test it with Benchmark.js by your own. From my own Jsperf tests, Proxy was ridiculously slow, not a thing the one would like to have in performance-critical place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy is supported natively in Node.js 6 (see [Node.js ES 6 support](http://node.green/#Proxy)). Just update Node.js to version 6 and you'll be able to use Proxy without any shims.